# In Joomla In htaccess REQUEST_URI is always returning index.php instead of SEF URL

Tags: htaccess, joomla

I have installed joomsef version 3.9.9 with the Joomla 1.5.25. Now I want to set https for some of the section of my site(e.g URI starts with /events/) while wanting rest of all urls on http.I am setting rules in .htaccess file but not getting output as expected. I am checking REQUEST_URI of the SEF urls but always getting index.php as URI.

Here is my htaccess code.

```
########## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
########## End - Custom redirects


#  Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
#  is not directly related to physical file paths.
#  Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root)

# RewriteBase /


########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section

# Here is my code e.g site url is http://mydomain.com/events

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(events)$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !ON
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{REQUEST_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I am not getting why REQUEST_URI is reffering index.php even though my url in address bar is like this http://mydomain.com/events . I am using JOOMSEF(Joomla extension for SEF URLS).If I am removing other rules from the htaccess file then joomla stops working. I am not getting a way to handle this as I am not expert.Please let me know if someone has passed through same situation and have solution or suggest some work around.

---

**EDIT:**

Above problem is not solved completely. I have put the code at the correct place and then tried some of the rewrite rules. But it's not working properly. I doubt URL is rewritten more than one time. Actually I am setting HTTPS for all the URLs under "events" section and rest of all on http. Here is my code.

```
##
# @version $Id: htaccess.txt 21064 2011-04-03 22:12:19Z dextercowley $
# @package Joomla
# @copyright Copyright (C) 2005 - 2010 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU/GPL
# Joomla! is Free Software
##


#####################################################
#  READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
#
#####################################################

##  Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

#
#  mod_rewrite in use

RewriteEngine On


########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
## If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
## This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
## Deny access to extension xml files (uncomment out to activate)
#<Files ~ "\.xml$">
#Order allow,deny
#Deny from all
#Satisfy all
#</Files>
## End of deny access to extension xml files
# Block out any script trying to set a mosConfig value through the URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits


########## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
########## End - Custom redirects




#  Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
#  is not directly related to physical file paths.
#  Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root)

# RewriteBase /
# Section I coded
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(events)
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.mydomainname.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(events)
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.mydomainname.com/$1 [L]

########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section
```

When I set following condition above those rules then its working as expected.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
```

So I doubt that URL is re written twice or more than that. First time with SEF URI "/events" and second time for "index.php". I have used [L] directive as well but it doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something to set or it could be problem with rules.Please suggest.

Comment: I have updated the post with more specific details. I am still facing problem and getting index.php as request URI.It seems like url get re-written more than one time. Please check the details in my original post and suggest some way to deal with this.

Comment: This should be a comment or edit on your own question, but you seem to have logged in as a different user so you have lost rights to edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you need to move your redirect code to execute before the core SEF code rewrites the request internally to index.php.

I would try this:

```
########## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
########## End - Custom redirects


#  Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
#  is not directly related to physical file paths.
#  Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root)

# RewriteBase /


# Here is my code e.g site url is http://mydomain.com/events

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(events)$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !ON
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{REQUEST_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/$1 [L,R=301]


########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section
```

Comment: I tried putting my code before core sef section and it worked.Thank  you HeatfanJohn for your quick help.

Comment: You're welcome.  The key to .htaccess is that the `[L]` option is for "Last rule" and tells Apache to stop processing if the rule matches.